# Two electrons, initially at rest, are separated by a distance $r$. What will be the distance between them after a time $t$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, electrons, coulombs-law

I thought a lot about it but couldn't come to an answer. It's obvious that there must be an equation telling the answer. If one of the electrons were fixed, by Integral calculus, I would have found an answer, but when both the electrons are free to move, I am struggling to find a solution.

Comment: The description depends on your choice of reference frame. I would attach my coordinate axes to one of the two electrons so that the distance between them is equal to the coordinate of the other electron. Then use Newton's second law for the other electron.

Comment: I think i got it. Could you make an actual expression(equation) for the 'distance' as mentioned in the question?

Comment: Sorry, that's not the site policy here.